# Unable to turn off notices in php.ini

Tags: php, iis, error-reporting

I am using PHP 5.2 and I have configured it in windows server. I have updated the php.ini file to turn off errors and notices. I have tried error_reporting =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE and display_errors = Off. But it is not reflecting while echo phpinfo() function. And sure that I am working in correct php.ini file. When i use error_reporting(0) in a php file, it is working well and doesn't show any errors and notices. Please help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you restarted apache after changes

Comment: Nope. I will check it now.

Comment: The php.ini file is loaded _once_ when the php module is loaded into the http server. That is why it is documented everywhere that you have to restart the http server to get that file read in again.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. It worked after restarting the server.

Comment: Add your own answer that the server needs to be restarted and accept it to close this question then, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this by restarting the server. Thanks.